# How to send filtered param to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have a photo carousel directive like that

```
<mz-photo-carousel items-per-slide=6
                   carousel-data="vm.carouselData">
</mz-photo-carousel>
```

inside the directive its just html to show carousel with the passed data

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in vm.carouselData">
     ....
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to send filtered data to the mz-photo-carousel directive like this:

```
<mz-photo-carousel items-per-slide=6
                   carousel-data="vm.carouselData | myFilter:param">
</mz-photo-carousel>
```

I dont want to filter inside the mz-photo-carousel directive because I want to leave it generic to deal with only data that it gets.

Comment: This code isn't enough to understand the issue, could you please share a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the problem!

Comment: here is a JSFiddle for you guys:
http://jsfiddle.net/y9arvut1/1/

look at this line of code: <array-display array="array | slice:0:5"></array-display>

Im trying to pass a filtered array to the directive and I get errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since you set two way data binding to the `array` attribute.

Reference taken from the SO Answer:

<kbd>**SO Answer**</kbd>

> When you pass filter job to your directive, angular will place a watch
>   on your jobs variable. So when jobs gets assigned in directive watch
>   get called, which will trigger filter again, and this will goes on
>   until maximum digest cycle reached by angular.
>
> To avoid this situation, you can create a filter method and pass that
>   method in ng-model. This way you can avoid both copy creation and
>   maximum digest cycle error.

So inorder to eliminate the error. Use the filter inside the directive using the below JS. Demo is also provided.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('arrayDisplay', function($parse, $filter){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {array: '=', from: '=', to:'='},
        template: '<span>{{array}}<span>after the filter is applied : {{filtered}}</span></span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.filtered = $filter('slice')(scope.array, scope.from, scope.to);
        }
    }
 });

demo.filter('slice', function() {
    return function(input, from, to) {
        return input.slice(from, to);  
  };
})

function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];   

};
```

Comment: This answer is not really helpful, as I said before, I don't want to use the filter inside the directive meaning I dont want any use of $filter in link function or filter inside the directive html or any other options that force me to filter inside the directive. I simply want to filter outside the directive and get the filtered value as param to the directive as I show in the demo

Comment: @RonYaari Ok I get it, you have a problem with this method, another option is to use `$watch` , please refer this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmjn5q33/), but please note, if you use filtering like what is done fiddle you have, that will trigger the error `10 $digest() iterations reached.`

Comment: what you offered with the $watch still not good enough for my case, because you still filter the array in the controller, my simple question is that if there anyway to filter it like this: 
    <array-display array="array | slice:0:5"></array-display>

Comment: @RonYaari Applogies, I don't know the solution to this :( Thanks for your time!